# Unselected object looks strange in sculpt/edit mode

Tags: modeling

[image]

[image]

[image]

The first image is object mode and second image is sculpt/edit mode. When zoomed in, it's like the third picture.
What's the reason for this?

Comment: Hi this is Z clipping, look at the toolbar to View window and try to change Clip Start value if it helps... 

If there is not a second object below it that causes it, then it can be your GPU as well

Comment: Hi I checked it out but Changing the Clip start value was not solution, and there's no other object below. Well, my graphics card is RX 6700XT Is this the cause?

Comment: I have same card and I have same clipping issue in Edit mode (it seems it is GPU card, 6700xt is new and drivers are not optimized perfectly for blender, I already posted it on devs and the solution is to wait to get better optimization or sell it and buy other card... )
But I found solution to make it less visible, you may try it as well (I will post it as answer to use image)

Comment: Hi, I am just letting you know that this issue was finally resolved by AMD, you can download beta driver already that fixes this issue here:
https://code.blender.org/2021/11/next-level-support-for-amd-gpus/
This driver let's you use AMD GPU in 3.0.0 but also fixes this Z clipping issue as well

Comment: Wow, It's finally solved! Thank you for letting me know like this. I'll try it right away. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: No problem I have already downloaded it and Cycles X in 3.0.0 runs 20% faster than default Cycles with this new driver and HIIP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what helped me:
[image]

Turning of this option will remove those clippings on inactive meshes. It may not be best solution, but it will help

Comment: it's solved! I didn't know GPU was the cause.... Thank you

Comment: Yea it unfortunately is, I have tried different drivers, all blender versions but it is compability between card and blender, other softwares work fine, Max, Maya, C4D and sketch I have tried... Only blender and this card have some issues together... Lets hope it will be fixed